# html not showing up on Android

Tags: android, css, html

I have an element which has the following css.

```
background: #ccc;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
```

I have tested the website on android 2.3 and it works fine, but when I load it on a device that runs 4.0, the element does not show up. I have inspect it with Adobe Edge Inspect(formerly Adobe Shadow) and it changes the `background` property to `background:initial`, I have tried overriding it with anything else but the inspector will go back to `background:initial`.

Is there Anything I can do to fix it or is this just a device bug? (it loads properly on mobile chrome)

**EDIT:** It only happens in one page, homepage

**EDIT 2:** Here is the html in question

    
        menu

```
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="" rel="nofollow"><img title="" src="" alt=""/></a></h1>

    <div class="social">
        <ul>
            <li class="rss" title="RSS"><a href="">RSS</a></li>
            <li class="twitter" title="Twitter"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
            <li class="facebook" title="Facebook"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
            <li>
                <form action="" class="searchform" method="get">
                    <div class="searchform">
                        <label for="s" class="skip"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="s" value="" name="s" class="watermark" placeholder="search"  />
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchsubmit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end #inner-header -->

<div class="navigation-container" id="main-navigation">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul id="menu-nav" class="">
            <li id="menu-item-8" class=""><a href=""</li>
            <li id="menu-item-17747" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-7" class=" menu-item-7"><a href=""></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-6" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-5" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <form action="" class="searchform" method="get">
                        <div class="searchform">
                            <label for="s" class="skip"></label>
                            <input type="text" id="s" value="" name="s" class="watermark" placeholder="search"  />
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchsubmit" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="facebook" title="Facebook"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="twitter" title="Twitter"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="rss" title="RSS"><a href="">RSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

As you may or may not have noted, this is pard of a wordpress theme and this is placed in the header, so every page has this exact same header. For some reason, this only breaks on the homepage. Another note, I have removed a lot of identifying information so the links don't have urls and other things are missing but all the elements are there

Comment: Have you tried using a *rrggbb* color? May just not like the *rgb* format: `#CCCCCC`.

Comment: @Phil Yes I just did, still nothing

Comment: If your HTML isn't showing up, wouldn't it be a good idea to give us your HTML as well?

Comment: @CodyGuldner I don't think it will help much since all the pages share the same identical header, but I have added the html anyways

Comment: Check if the wordpress theme has a default layout for mobile devices that it's overwriting your CSS.

Comment: @BarbaraPM it is only on the homepage and only on android 4.0 and there is no other theme affecting it